# layouts designed in sketch software doesnt match when implemented in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, sketchapp

I have set a linear layout as 32 dp in sketch app using mac and when the same dimesnsions implemented in android studio and then i took the screen shot and imported to sketch app and when compared with the sketch designed measurements there was a huge difference in the height i.e the height was 44dp so can some help me out in this how to match exact measurements from sketch to android layouts.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this problem many times and found this solution which worked for me

In sketch first use the art-board which fits material design 
for eg: 360 x 640

Get you design fit in height can vary and than try to export your design using zeplin, creat your android project using zeplin and export all your screens, zeplin will help you telling exact font, font size, images size also it allows to copy xml to be used in android studio and this give almost perfect result only difference while comparing is android bottom buttons and screens you need to adjust manually